# Is it possible to put Angular Material table directives into separate files?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

Is it possible to move parts of Material table into separate files? F.e. move `matColumnDef` into a new `ColumnDefComponent`, to make table definition cleaner.

```html
<table mat-table>
  <!-- Current solution -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Id</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.id}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Desired solution -->
  <my-column-def></my-column-def>
  <my-other-column-def></my-other-column-def>
  ...

  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
</table>
```

With a basic approach, the directives will not be working properly:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-basic-material-table-example-wthva4?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Check out the [example](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples#table-wrapped) about table wrapper in the official docs. It does exactly that using `ng-content`.

Comment: @TotallyNewb Thank you, I've considered this option, however the issue is that I can only split logic into two files. I'm using 5 types of columns definitions and I'd like to put each one in a separate file. Unluckily directives will not be resolved in such case, f.e.:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-table-wrap-tgsrqr?file=src/app/app.component.html